How to retrieve document using azure_data_cosmos in rust
Has anyone ever worked with the azure_data_cosmos crate? I'm not able to get even the simplest operation going of retrieving a document using the partition and resourcename. All the examples I find are only about adding documents to the database. I want to retrieve one. Does anyone have a simple example on how to do this. I am able to connect the database, collection and even return the collection name to me. I do not het how to extract the actual document content after retrieving the document.
This is what I got so far:
let authorization_token = AuthorizationToken::primary_key(&primary_key)?;

// Next we will create a Cosmos client.
let client = CosmosClient::new(account, authorization_token);

// Get a reference to the database
let database_client = client.clone().database_client(database_name);

// Get a reference to the collection
let collection_client = database_client
    .clone()
    .collection_client(collection_name);

// Define the document ID you want to retrieve
let document_id = "my_doc_id";
let partition_key = "my_doc_permission";

// Create a DocumentClient
let document_client = collection_client.document_client(document_id, &partition_key);
//retrieve the document
let response = document_client.unwrap().get_document();


indeed it does. Still no document though

You already asked a near-identical question here that was closed. And in that question, I suggested you edit to provide a [mcve]. Same suggestion here. This includes things like a sample document, expected vs actual outcome, errors, etc. Otherwise, it's hard to know what, specifically, your issue is.

@DavidMakogon this is because I'm looking for help. I already did not understand why the last question was closed. Believe me If I had all the details I would have figured it out myself. To me the questions seems obvious but I could be wrong. How do I extract the actual document after the get_document?


NB: I have never used azure_data_cosmos, nor Cosmos DB more generally, nor indeed any of Azure.  I have no particular knowledge of any of them.  I am answering this question from a brief minute's perusal of azure_data_cosmos's API documentation (and a glance at some of the source code), starting by searching for the get_document method from the OP's code.  Nevertheless, whilst the following code is untested, the API alone suggests that it is correct.

The DocumentClient::get_document call that you are making appears to be a little bit of a misnomer, as it does not actually get anything from (nor indeed communicate at all with) the database; instead it appears merely to return a GetDocumentBuilder that you can use to send such a request to the database when you are ready to do so.
It appears that you do that by .awaiting the Future that is returned by its .into_future() method.  That future, when it completes, produces a Result<GetDocumentResponse<T>>.  This contains the retrieved document (provided there weren't any errors).
Therefore, you probably want to do something along the following lines:
let document = match response.into_future().await? {
    GetDocumentResponse::Found(found) => found.document,
    GetDocumentResponse::NotFound(_) => todo!("handle document not found"),
};

Provided there were no errors, you will now have document that is a Document<T>.  If you want to access the T-typed data within, you will need to use its document field:
let data = document.document;

